# binding a label to a property

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'd like to bind a label to a property of a class and tried this:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Test test = new Test () { Name = "abc" };
label.DataBindings.Add ("Text", test, "Name");
```

This shows "abc" at the label. If I change the Name property after the data binding, the label does not reflect the new value. What's wrong?

Comment: Your class has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: [Check the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the binding other way.

```
label.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", test, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

I hope this works for you!

Another way is to update your class to use value changed events,

```
class Test
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            //Check if you are assigning the same value
            if (Equals(name, value))
                return;
            name = value;
            OnNameChanged();
        }

        public event EventHandler NameChanged;

        protected virtual void OnNameChanged()
        {
            var handler = NameChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In case the first one doesn't work.

The best solution is to do it generic way,

```
class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using a value changed event in your property, just like I mentioned in my edit.

Comment: The first solution does not work neither (I tried it already). The second may work, but this is much more code than I'd like to write for such a small problem ;-)

Comment: The second solution works (beside a small syntax error you had), but I still hope there is a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: Yeah, you can also use INotifyPropertyChanged with your class. That's a generic one.